# Unable To Implement Thymeleaf 3.0Decoupled Logic, Template is not getting populated with data?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I want to try decoupled template logic using thymeleaf. This is mentioned here in  [thymeleaf 3.0 documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#decoupled-template-logic).

1. According to tutorial I have created my project [here](https://github.com/SageGandhi/Learning/tree/master/TemplatingThymeLeaf)
2. My template & decoupled logic is present inside [LogicTemplate.html](https://github.com/SageGandhi/Learning/blob/master/TemplatingThymeLeaf/src/main/resources/templates/html/LogicTemplate.html) & [LogicTemplate.th.xml](https://github.com/SageGandhi/Learning/blob/master/TemplatingThymeLeaf/src/main/resources/templates/html/LogicTemplate.th.xml) file.
3. Code Snippet For LogicTemplate.html is as follows:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>ThymeLeaf:Example03</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="ProductTable">
  <tr>
   <td class="Name">Name</td>
   <td class="Price">Price</td>
   <td class="InStock">In Stock</td>
   <td class="Comments">Comments</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="Name">Ppap</td>
   <td class="Price">10</td>
   <td class="InStock">Yes</td>
   <td class="Comments">No Comments</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

4. Code Snippet For LogicTemplate.th.xml is as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<thlogic>
  <attr sel="#ProductTable" th:remove="all-but-first">
    <attr sel="/tr[0]" th:each="prod : ${products}">
      <attr sel="td.Name" th:text="${prod.name}" />
      <attr sel="td.Price" th:text="${prod.price}" />
      <attr sel="td.InStock" th:text="${prod.inStock}" />
      <attr sel="td.Comments" th:text="${${prod.comments!=null and (not #lists.isEmpty(prod.comments))}?#lists.size(prod.comments):0}}" />
    </attr>
  </attr>
</thlogic>
```

5. I have created following java class [DeCoupledLogic](https://github.com/SageGandhi/Learning/blob/master/TemplatingThymeLeaf/src/main/java/edu/gandhi/prajit/thymeleaf/DeCoupledLogic.java),Code snippet shown below: 
`

```
public class DeCoupledLogic {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final FileTemplateResolver templateResolverFile = new FileTemplateResolver();
            templateResolverFile.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
            templateResolverFile.setPrefix("src/main/resources/templates/html/");
            templateResolverFile.setSuffix(".html");
            templateResolverFile.setCacheTTLMs(1 * 60 * 60 * 1000l);
            templateResolverFile.setCacheable(Boolean.TRUE);
            templateResolverFile.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            templateResolverFile.setCheckExistence(true);
            templateResolverFile.setUseDecoupledLogic(true);
            templateResolverFile.setCheckExistence(true);

            final StandardDecoupledTemplateLogicResolver resolver=new StandardDecoupledTemplateLogicResolver();
            resolver.setPrefix("src/main/resources/templates/html/");

            final TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
            templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolverFile);
            templateEngine.setDecoupledTemplateLogicResolver(resolver);

            final Context context01 = new Context();
            context01.setVariable("products",ProductRepository.getInstance().findAll());

            final BufferedWriter writer01=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
            templateEngine.process("LogicTemplate",context01,writer01);     
        }
    }
```

`
But executing this code does not gives desired result.
Output Actual:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>ThymeLeaf:Example03</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="ProductTable">
  <tr>
   <td class="Name">Name</td>
   <td class="Price">Price</td>
   <td class="InStock">In Stock</td>
   <td class="Comments">Comments</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="Name">Ppap</td>
   <td class="Price">10</td>
   <td class="InStock">Yes</td>
   <td class="Comments">No Comments</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```

Output Expected:
Must not contain this static text but all product information.But I am unable to figure out where this code piece went wrong.Please Help me to identify potential error in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thymeleaf configures a `StandardDecoupledTemplateLogicResolver` by default (and the one you are configuring looks like it is configured wrong).  I was able to get your files to work by changing it to this:

```
final FileTemplateResolver templateResolverFile = new FileTemplateResolver();
templateResolverFile.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
templateResolverFile.setPrefix("src/main/resources/templates/html/");
templateResolverFile.setSuffix(".html");
templateResolverFile.setCacheTTLMs(1 * 60 * 60 * 1000l);
templateResolverFile.setCacheable(Boolean.TRUE);
templateResolverFile.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
templateResolverFile.setCheckExistence(true);
templateResolverFile.setUseDecoupledLogic(true);
templateResolverFile.setCheckExistence(true);

final TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolverFile);

final Context context01 = new Context();
context01.setVariable("products",ProductRepository.getInstance().findAll());

final BufferedWriter writer01=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
templateEngine.process("LogicTemplate",context01,writer01);
```

Also, you have some typos in your logic xml, it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<thlogic>
    <attr sel="#ProductTable" th:remove="all-but-first">
        <attr sel="/tr[0]" th:each="prod : ${products}">
            <attr sel="td.Name" th:text="${prod.name}" />
            <attr sel="td.Price" th:text="${prod.price}" />
            <attr sel="td.InStock" th:text="${prod.inStock}" />
            <attr sel="td.Comments" th:text="${prod.comments != null and (not #lists.isEmpty(prod.comments)) ? #lists.size(prod.comments) : 0}" />
        </attr>
    </attr>
</thlogic>
```